# Closure of an open ball in a weird subset?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $E = ([0, 1] × \{0\}) ∪ (\{0\} × [0, 1])$ be a subset of $\mathbf{R}^2$ 
endowed with the metric induced from $(\mathbf{R}^2, ||\cdot||_{\infty})$.

-Surely $E=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, that seems logical to me?

What are the open and the closed balls of centre $(1/2,0)$ in this new metric space.

-I would think the open ball is $(0,1)\times [0,1/2]$ and the closed ball is  $[0,1]\times [0,1/2]$

Show that the closure of the open ball is a proper subset of the closed ball

-now this is where I am stuck,  sure the closed ball and the closure of the open ball are the same here?  That would probably imply my first 2 answers are wrong

Comment: > -Surely $E=[0,1]\times[0,1]$, that seems logical to me?

No: $(1,1)$ is in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, but not in $E$. Everything else that you say is inevitably wrong, because they all follow from this. 

> sure the closed ball and the closure of the open ball are the same here?

Even if everything else were correct, this would still not be true: $(0,1)\times[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ is a proper subset of $[0,1]\times[0,\frac{1}{2}]$: the latter contains $(0,0)$, but the former does not.

Comment: I missed out some braces around the 0s although I don't know if that changes anything.  

So i thought E was a rectangle but its not.  its 2 lines that intesect at (0,0).

Comment: @TobyPeterken That's right.

Comment: It's two segments meeting at their endpoint, of shape L

Comment: open balls of what radius?? there is no such thing as **the** open ball.